# Sort date using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to know how to sort a list that has a date as a field using Lambda expression. the list should be sorted based on the closest date (after then before) a specific date (e.g birthday).

if we have the following days:

10/11/2015
10/13/2015
10/14/2015
10/15/2015
10/15/2015
10/22/2015

and the birth date is 10/14/2015

the dates will be sorted as

10/14/2015
10/15/2015
10/15/2015
10/13/2015
10/11/2015
10/22/2015

- the first result will be the given date(in this case birth date)
- then the nearest date greater than it
- or the nearest date less than it
- a date that is 10 days greater than the given date will come after a date that is 9 days less than the given date

Thanks!

Comment: Reads like a homework assignment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're ordering by here is the distance between the pivot (the birthdate) and each date. Something like this:

```
var sorted = data.OrderBy(date => (birthdate - date).TotalDays);
```

will sort by distance, but put all the *after* dates first, because the TotalDays will be negative, then the *before* dates. To avoid that, we need to implement a custom IComparer which compares absolute values, and falls back to the real values in case of equality:

```
public class AbsoluteComparer : IComparer<double>
{
    public int Compare(double x, double y)
    {
        var absX = Math.Abs(x);
        var absY = Math.Abs(y);

        if (absX > absY)  
            return 1;
        if (absX < absY)
            return -1;

        // If Absolutes are equal, determine by sign.
        if (x > y)
            return 1;
        if (y > x)
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

So the final call would be:

```
var sorted = data.OrderBy(date => (birthdate - date).TotalDays, new AbsoluteComparer());
```

Comment: `ThenBy()` makes it easy.

Comment: Uh... that kind of a long way of writing `Math.Abs((birthdate - date).TotalDays)` isn't it?

Comment: Check out the previous edit to see why that isn't sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
           List<string> input = new List<string>() {"10/11/2015", "10/13/2015", "10/14/2015", "10/15/2015", "10/15/2015", "10/22/2015"};
            List<DateTime> dateArray = input.Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();

            DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse("10/14/2015");

            dateArray.Sort((x, y) => Math.Abs((x - birthday).Ticks).CompareTo(Math.Abs((y - birthday).Ticks)));
```